# Shorten down ifs for grid checking

Tags: python

I'm in the making of a 4-in-a-Row game with a grid system. Was thinking of shortening it down with a `for` loop, but it ended up making the player randomly win. Any tips is appreciated.

```
if grid[4][row] == '.':
    grid[4][row] = 'X'
else:
    if grid[3][row] == '.':
        grid[3][row] = 'X'
    else:
        if grid[2][row] == '.':
            grid[2][row] = 'X'
        else:
            if grid[1][row] == '.':
                grid[1][row] = 'X'
            else: 
                if grid[0][row] == '.':
                    grid[0][row] = 'X'
```

Comment: can you explain the logic you are trying to implement?

Comment: This if statement could be "shortened" with a for loop.

Comment: Please put the code using `for` that wasn't working in your question.

Comment: It's used to check if the grid slot is available for the player to put their marker, if its available it changes it to the marker. Otherwise it moves it further up putting it there instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right off the bat, you can use `elif`:

```
if grid[4][row] == '.':
    grid[4][row] = 'X'
elif grid[3][row] == '.':
    grid[3][row] = 'X'
elif grid[2][row] == '.':
    grid[2][row] = 'X'
elif grid[1][row] == '.':
    grid[1][row] = 'X'
elif grid[0][row] == '.':
    grid[0][row] = 'X'
```

You can then replace this with a simple loop which will exit early if it finds a `.`:

```
for n in range(4, -1, -1):
    if grid[n][row] == '.':
        grid[n][row] = 'X'
        break
```

If `grid` is a list, you can use a reversed slice instead of iterating over specific indices.

```
for c in grid[4::-1]:
    if c[row] == '.':
        c[row] = 'X'
        break
```

If you want to get fancier, use `any` with an assignment expression:

```
if any((c:=grid[n])[row] == '.' for n in range(4, -1, -1)):
    c[row] = 'X'

# Or for a list,
# if any((c:=x)[row] == '.' for x in grid[4::-1]):
#     c[row] = 'X'
```

As soon as `any` sees a value of `n` (or `x`) that makes the expression true, it returns `True`, and the name `c` remains bound to the element of `grid` that made the expression true.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what is the logic you are trying to implement, but equivalent to your code is:

```
for index in range(4, -1, -1):
    if grid[index][row] == '.':
        grid[index][row] = 'X'
        break
```

Comment: This answer could benefit from more explanation, as in @chepner's answer.

Comment: I agree chepner lists more options, but in my opinion the answer provided for this specific option is not substantially more detailed